# Django Rest Framework Cache Headers

Tags: python, django, caching, django-rest-framework, cdn

I'm trying to cache some of my DRF api calls in a CDN. I need the following headers Cache-Control:public, max-age=XXXX

This is pretty easy when you're using traditional django templating, you just add the @cache_page() @cache_control(public=True) decorators, but for DRF, I can't find anything similar. There's quite a bit about in mem caches, which I already have up, but I'd really like to get the CDN to take that load off my server all together, I'd like to cache the resulting queryset.

I'm also using modelViewSets if that matters for anything:

```
class EventViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    serializer_class = EventViewSet
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
    pagination_class = pagination.LimitOffsetPagination
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend, filters.SearchFilter,)
    filter_class = EventFilter
    search_fields = ('name','city','state')

    def get_queryset(self):
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@method_decorator` [can be applied to the view class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class). When provided with a `name` argument, it will wrap that named method in instances of that class. What you want is something along the lines of:

```py
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_control

@method_decorator(cache_control(public=True, max_age=xxxx), name='dispatch')
class EventViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you try:

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_control

class EventViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    @method_decorator(cache_control(private=False, max_age=xxxx)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(EventViewSet, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `django.views.decorators.cache` was deprecated after Django 3.2 (although I wasn't able to confirm the exact version of deprecation, not even in [Django's deprecation timeline](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/deprecation/)). This makes @tomchuk's answer obsolete as of november 2023.

A possible alternative, with similar usage, is to implement a middleware that leverages the `django.utils.cache.patch_cache_control`, and attach it to the view using one of `django.utils.decorators.decorator_from_middleware{,_with_args}`:

```py
from django.utils.cache import patch_cache_control
from django.utils.decorators import (
    decorator_from_middleware_with_args,
    method_decorator,
)

class CacheHeaderMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, func, **kwargs):
        self.options = kwarg

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        patch_cache_control(response, **self.options)
        return response

control_cache = decorator_from_middleware_with_args(CacheHeaderMiddleware)

@method_decorator(control_cache(max_age=3600), name='dispatch')
class TheViewClass:
    ...
```

Note that, as in @tomchuk answer, we still need to use `method_decorator` to turn a function decorator into a class decorator. Note also that the decorators `decorator_from_middleware{,_with_args}` [expect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.decorators.decorator_from_middleware) a

> middleware that’s compatible with the old style of Django 1.9 and
> earlier (having methods like `process_request()`, `process_exception()`,
> and `process_response()`).

More information about different styles of middleware can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/middleware/#upgrading-pre-django-1-10-style-middleware).

Answer (score -1):

Update: I never solved the problem within Django or Django Rest Framework. I ended up setting the headers in our nginx conf file.